# SQL Import Wizard Row Delimiter Text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a flat text file with this content :

```
 1,1970360,57484768/0001-03,204,Bossa
 Nossa,Solo,6212-G,2,M,27/04/2015,21/06/2015,26/2015,15,5142,1970356,AMOSTRA,
,27/04/2015
1,1970361,57484768/0001-03,204,Bossa
Nossa,Solo,6212-G,2,M,27/04/2015,21/06/2015,26/2015,15,5142,1970357,AMOSTRA,
,27/04/2015
1,1971182,57484768/0001-03,204,Bossa
Nossa,Solo,6212-G,2,M,28/04/2015,21/06/2015,26/2015,15,5142,1970358,AMOSTRA,
,28/04/2015
1,1971188,57484768/0001-03,204,Bossa
Nossa,Solo,6212-G,2,M,28/04/2015,21/06/2015,26/2015,15,5142,1970355,AMOSTRA,
,28/04/2015
```

I know the column delimiter is "," the last column is the date late the word AMOSTRA, but what is the row delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from what you pasted - the editor seems to have added more end-of-line characters. Is there a return between **Bossa** and **Nossa**?

Most text files are both Carriage Return and Line Feed - **{CR}{LF}**. If you got it from some funky source (Unix, MAC), it may only have a **Line Feed {LF}**.

You should be able to select one and check it with the Preview to make sure that it's right.

You might try opening the file in **NotePad++**. You can view the End-of-Line characters by going to **View -> Show Symbol - > Show End of Line**.